# Selenium+Python: for.. (loop) doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is my code. What I am trying to do is to print all hotel names in all 
pages with the search term "BERLIN, GERMANY".
While I press the 'run' button in Pycharm there is nothing printed in screen.
Can anyone figure out what is the mistake in my code?

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC    
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

my_list = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Python27\\selenium\\webdriver\\chrome\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('http://booking.com')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#ss").send_keys("BERLIN, GERMANY")

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sb-searchbox__button").click()

hotel_name = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".sr-hotel__name")

visible_next=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".paging-next")

driver.maximize_window()

for link in hotel_name:

        scrap_hotel_name = link.text

        print (scrap_hotel_name)

        my_list.append(scrap_hotel_name)

        while True:

            click_icon = WebDriverWait(driver, 4).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located([By.LINK_TEXT, 'Next page']))

            click_icon.click()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess this is because your `hotel_name` is empty... Can you try to `print(hotel_name)`?

Comment: @Andersson Thank you for your answer! When I'm changing to print(hotel_name) it print's only the selenium value of the first hotel name and click's on the 2nd page...and stuck's there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the logic of your script:

1. Your `hotel_name` defined out of loop. That means that you gets the list of elements just once- on the first page only;
2. Your `visible_next` variable defined, but you don't use it;
3. The `while` loop inside `for` loop intents to click "Next" button time after time without executing the rest of `for` loop lines (they will be executed only once- on the first page)

Try below code to get hotel names from all of the pages:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://booking.com')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#ss").send_keys("BERLIN, GERMANY")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.sb-searchbox__button").click()
my_list = []

while True:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located([By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class^="sr-usp-overlay"]']))
    my_list.extend([hotel.text for hotel in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.sr-hotel__name')])
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-page-next]"])).click()
    except:
        break

[print(hotel) for hotel in my_list]
```

In `Python 2.x` replace last line with

```
for hotel in my_list:
    print(hotel)
```

Comment: I did this and I have the same issue. It loads automatically 1-2 pages. In the 2nd page it stuck and also doesn't print anything. :(
Shouldn't declare 'hotel' somewhere before the 'While.." ?

Comment: What do you mean *stuck*? Do you get any exception? Code works fine with `Python 3.6`. There could be some issues with `Python 2.7`, but I need to know what exactly doesn't work as for now I have only `3.6` version and can't check code with `2.7`

Comment: I did the above change and it prints the results of each page BUT to print the hotel names of each page I must hit the 'X' button in browser next to the 'refresh' button. Otherwise it stays in same page each time!
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable([By.CSS_SELECTOR, "*[data-page-next]"])).click()
        for hotel in my_list:
            print(hotel)

Comment: Ok, I see there is an issue with an 2.7version. I will change into 3.6 the soonest and I will let you know!

Comment: you are a **rockstar**. It worked athough I must test it in large amount of pages...(I will let you know). Could you please expain to me what is happening between 'While'...'try'? Also could you please advise me some resources to read/study about selenium+python+webscraping? Thank you!!

Comment: The `while` loop starts with waiting for modal window (that appears each time new page loaded) to disappear. Than new hotel names added to list of hotels. Finally, in `try`/`except` you're trying to wait until "Next" button becomes clickable to click it. If it's not clickable then it means that you are on the last page and script should be stopped

Comment: You can read official [documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) as well as StackOverFlow documentation for [`selenium`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium/topics) and [`selenium-webdriver`](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/selenium-webdriver/topics) to learn more about web-scraping with `selenium`

Comment: Thank you very much once again!